# Spark and Scala upgrade on CDH

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cloudera-cdh

I currently have a CDH with Spark 1.6.0 and Scala 2.10.5. I would like to upgrade the Spark version to 2.0.0 and Scala version to 2.11.x and make these as defaults.

I am currently trying this on a CDH Quickstart VM but would like to extend this to a Spark cluster with CDH distribution.

Could someone help on how to go about these two upgrades?

Thank you.

Comment: You want to do that cluster wide? Are you sure the other CDH components support those versions? Are there parcels available to do that for you? Otherwise, have you tried to use the package manager in the OS, which I think is `yum`?

Comment: Yes. I want to do it cluster wide...mine is a small cluster with 3 nodes only though...For Spark, it looks like getting the new distribution and set the SPARK_HOME accordingly...check this link: https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Advanced-Analytics-Apache-Spark/upgrade-spark-from-1-2-to-1-3/td-p/25633. Yet to figure out how to do this...not sure about Scala version though

Comment: You install Scala the same way as spark. Download and install / extract into your PATH

Comment: Is there is a list of associated environment variables that need to be updated? I see SPARK_HOME as one...but in CDH can't get its current path...which variables need to be updated for Scala?

Comment: PATH and JAVA_HOME, probably. I don't think Scala has specific variables

Comment: Just updated Spark to 2.0.0 using the above said method...It seems to work fine...Along with Spark, Scala also got updated automatically...spark-shell shows the most recent version of Scala...didnt have to do anything additional...yet to try it on the cluster though